# Can not upload file/image in flaskapp

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-appbuilder

I have created a form in html/php, and using flask for backend.

Everything is working perfect except when I am trying to upload image I am always seeing the error:

```
error is**"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment"**
```

my flaskapp code snippet is

```
@app.route('/apple', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def apple():
  onlineAppForm = RegForm()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
           filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
           file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    except Exception as e:
        print "Form without file "+str(e)
    return render_template("apply2.html", data=data, filename=filename, form=onlineAppForm)
```

this is my upload folder

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
```

I am not getting where the error is.

```
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
```

this is my form

```
<tr>
    <td class="sectionheading">Upload Scanned Copies</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="12">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr id="photosignthumb_span" height="40">
    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="100%">&nbsp;<b>
        <span class="mandatory">*</span>
        Please upload scanned copies of your photo </b>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photofile"  
         method="post"/><br>
        Please upload your recent passport size photograph:max 
        80KB(Only JPEG and JPG formats)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="photosignthumb_span" height="40">
    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="100%">&nbsp;<b>
        <span class="mandatory">*</span>
        Please upload scanned copies of your signature </b> 
        <input type="file" name="sign" id="signfile" 
        method="post"/><br>
        Please upload your recent passport size photograph:max 
        80KB(Only JPEG and JPG formats)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What happen if `if file and allowed_file(file.filename)` does not pass or an *exception* raises?...`filename` obviously won't exist !

Comment: yes true that m getting, m not able to upload so yes filename won't exist, but what do i have to do to pass.

Comment: Can u post code of `allowed_file` and relevant template file (from which you are uploading your files) ?

Comment: `def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filename` existence depends on couple of conditions:

1 - `file = request.files['file']` 
2 - `if file and allowed_file(file.filename):` 
3 - No *exception* is raised.

So, if any of the above didn't happen, then `filename` won't spring into existence and hence your error message.

EDIT:

Quoting from `flask` [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/fileuploads/#uploading-files) on file upload:

> 1. A  tag is marked with enctype=multipart/form-data and an  is placed in that form.
> 2. The application accesses the file from the files dictionary on the request object.
> 3. Use the save() method of the file to save the file permanently somewhere on the filesystem.

Looking at the form your provided it seems you don't have any `form` block, you should have something like:

```
<form action="/apple" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
    <td class="sectionheading">Upload Scanned Copies</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="12">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr id="photosignthumb_span" height="40">
    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="100%">&nbsp;<b>
        <span class="mandatory">*</span>
        Please upload scanned copies of your photo </b>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photofile"  
         method="post"/><br>
        Please upload your recent passport size photograph:max 
        80KB(Only JPEG and JPG formats)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="photosignthumb_span" height="40">
    <td align="left" valign="middle" width="100%">&nbsp;<b>
        <span class="mandatory">*</span>
        Please upload scanned copies of your signature </b> 
        <input type="file" name="sign" id="signfile" 
        method="post"/><br>
        Please upload your recent passport size photograph:max 
        80KB(Only JPEG and JPG formats)
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
```